# How to handle ZeroMQ publisher crash?

Tags: python, c++, proxy, zeromq

I have a zmq proxy(XPUB/XSUB) running on a thread and some other publisher/subscribers connected to this proxy on python, and have a publisher code on C++. All connections are made using tcp on 127.0.0.1.

When I first start the system, it works as expected. Then I terminate the C++ side while keeping the python side on. When I restart the C++ side I do not get any messages on python side, while the pub/sub that lives on python works just fine.

Now I read some other threads and if I understand it correctly it is because subscribers to my C++ side still think the connection is on. So I restart the python code completely as well, with proxy included. However I still cannot get C++ side and python side communicate with each other, no matter how I restart each side.

To make things work again I have to restart my computer. When it restarts it works until I close C++ side again.

I would love to get a feedback on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: This feels like a tcp port reuse problem. In the connection strings your specifying a port. I don't know what zmq does but if it is cleanly shut down it will release the port. If you simply ^C the c++ or python code that is unlikely to be a clean shutdown, and it then depends on exactly how zmq sets up its socket,  and it may not mark it for address reuse. That would explain the need for a reboot.

Comment: You could test that hypothesis by doing what you're doing, but before you try running everything a second time (no reboot) change the port numbers in your connection strings.